# HQL : Getting the primary key of an object

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I am using HQL to save an object in the DB. It is something like this

```
Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(ASK_FOR_HELP_SAVE_QUERY);
        query.setInteger("status", askForHelp.getStatus());
        query.setString("requestId", askForHelp.getRequestId());
        query.setString("toAccountId", askForHelp.getToAccountId());
        query.setDate("creationDate", askForHelp.getCreationDate());
        query.executeUpdate()
```

;

Now i want the primary key(sequence in DB) of the created object in the DB. I cannot use the select query because no combination of fields will make this object unique in the DB , except the primary key.

I there a way to do this.

Thanks!
Pratik

Answer (score 2):

The foremost question is "why?" That is, unless you've really meant to type `createSQLQuery()` above.

If you're using HQL that means you already have your entity mapped. If that's the case, why not use `session.save()` or `session.saveOrUpdate()`? You can [configure a generator](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-id) for your entity's id and it will automatically be populated for you after the entity is saved.

For sequence you'd use something like:

```
<id name="id" type="long" column="my_id">
    <generator class="sequence">
            <param name="sequence">my_id_sequence</param>
    </generator>
</id>
```

Now, if you're actually using SQL and not HQL then you need to rethink your logic and select  current value for sequence prior to save.

Answer (score 0):

The Primary Key can be anything. If you don't know what it will be, then even if `Query` had some method returning `Object`, you couldn't cast to it.

The proper way to do what you are doing is **not** HQL. `Session` / `EntityManager` have a a number of methods (`save` / `persist` / `merge()`, etc), which set your primary key (if it is generated), and you can get it from via your object's getter.

Generally speaking, use HQL only for SELECTS. Even if an update/delete query seems the same as calling `delete()`, HQL doesn't handle cascades, so exceptions are inevitable.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using your query code, you should take advantage of the power of hibernate by just calling session.save() on your java objects e.g:

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(askForHelp);
```

And then straight after that, you can do this to get the object's primary key (assuming it's called id):

```
askForHelp.getId();
```